# How can I fetch the total amount of items?

Tags: stackexchange-api, stackexchange

I'd like to call for a stack exchange query to get the number of questions that were asked in a certain time range about a certain tag.

How can I do it? according to [api's documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) it said that:

> If you're looking to just **select total**, exclude the items field in
>   favor of excluding all the properties on the returned type.

How can I do it?

Comment: I found this so maybe the question isn't relevant: https://stackapps.com/questions/7293/how-to-get-the-number-count-total-of-tags-badges-something-from-the-api

Comment: Just updated that linked answer; thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass [a custom filter](https://stackapps.com/a/7832/7653) in the parameters to the API call.

For example:

[/2.2/questions?fromdate=1537056000&todate=1537660800&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=android&site=stackoverflow **&filter=!w-*Ytm8YGWVl9..xoC**](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1537056000&todate=1537660800&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=android&site=stackoverflow&filter=!w-*Ytm8YGWVl9..xoC)

Reference:

- [the `/questions` live-doc page for those parameters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2018-09-16&todate=2018-09-23&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=android&filter=!w-*Ytm8YGWVl9..xoC&site=stackoverflow&run=true).
- [**Useful and safe** canned filters](https://stackapps.com/a/7832/7653) (Unfortunately the doc page has terrible advice).
- [Creating and using custom filters](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653).

Comment: thanks Brock. How did you edit the filter, apart from checking the field 'total' in the '.wrapper' section, what else did you change?

Comment: OK, I checked 'total' and unchecked 'items' and it worked. Is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, that'll work, as long as you have `backoff` and `error_id` also checked.  (Additional strongly recommended fields are in the first referenced link above.)